# run a subprocess in a loop

Tags: python, loops, subprocess

I have for loop in Python. In each iteration of the loop I want to run a Bash script and after its termination continue the loop and again run the Bash script:

```
for batch in something:
    proc = Popen(['./mybash.sh'])
    proc.wait()
```

The `mybash.sh` script will compute something and display a value using `echo`. However, when I run this code it seems that it executes `mybash.sh` script only once, since I can only see the value displayed by `echo` only for the first iteration. What is wrong with the code? BTW, I am using Python 3.5

Comment: Could you check the return value about `proc.wait()`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I looped over a simple hello world script as you described above, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Can you clarify where you are seeing the output of your script? Does it open up a new console when you run your script? Can you try routing your `stdout` to a `subprocess.PIPE` and change `proc.wait()` to `print(proc.communicate())`. It is supposed to print out the output of your script.

Comment: You should ask the question about the problem you actually have…

Comment: @Xiwei Wang print(proc.wait()) outputs 0

Comment: @najeem in each iteration of the loop there are other operations which have been performed on GPU and they produce a text file on the disc. Then it is the Popen(['./mybash.sh']), and my bash script reads that text file and computes some score and then just use `echo` to show that score.

Comment: @LtWorf the problem is it only outputs once and does not show anything for the rest of the iterations of for-loop. When I discard proc.wait(), it outputs the same value for every iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of `it seems that it executes mybash.sh script only once` maybe cause by:

- Your iteration run only once.
- The `proc.wait()` does not return.
- The `./mybash.sh` not work correctly.

And you can change you script as this:

```
for batch in something:
    # to check the looping times
    print(batch)
    proc = Popen(['./mybash.sh'])
    # to check if the mybash.sh exit normally
    print(proc.wait())
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` merely *starts* a process.  You probably want something like

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

for batch in something:
    print(run(['./mybash.sh'],
        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
        check=True, universal_newlines=True).stdout)
```

The `check=True` assumes your script returns a useful and valid exit code.

For (much!) more, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Comment: It does not show the output, I have seen this post [Only first subprocess.Popen(…, stdin=f) in a loop works correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866386/only-first-subprocess-popen-stdin-f-in-a-loop-works-correctly) but I am not sure how relevant is to my problem

Comment: Does your script expect to receive some input? What is it actually doing?